# Do questions about spirits and other high alcohol-content brewing belong here?

Tags: discussion

I'm about to start making some higher alcohol-content spirits. Is this group specifically for beer and wine or would high-alcohol spirits (~20%) fall into this category as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes as admittedly interesting as it is, it's off-topic here.  A question like this belongs [in the meta site](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/), also.

Comment: I was afraid that this would've been the answer...

Comment: I don't understand why distilling is off topic. It seems like an arbitrary distinction when you consider how similar the processes are. I haven't been able to find any real meta discussion on this other than things that are mostly positive / warm to the idea of including it as on topic.